# `ls` behaving differently inside and outside of bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, synology

I am working on a Synology NAS. I have a list of files I want to delete, listed with full path in a file called `Myfiles.txt`. 
The file has circa 3000 lines like this:

```
"/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Life.Itself.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-FGT/RARBG.txt"
"/volume2/nbU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01.WEBRip.x264-ION10/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01E16.High.Stakes.Hip.Hop.WEBRip.x264-ION10.mp4"
"/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01.WEBRip.x264-ION10/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01E14.Time.to.Face.the.Music.WEBRip.x264-ION10.mp4"
```

I am using following script
(testing with `ls` to later replace with `rm -f`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="" read -r p;
do
  ls "$p"
done < "Myfiles.txt"
```

Unfortunately, when I execute the script, every single loop errors out with the following message:

```
ls: cannot access "/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Life.Itself.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-FGT/RARBG.txt": No such file or directory
ls: cannot access "/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01.WEBRip.x264-ION10/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01E16.High.Stakes.Hip.Hop.WEBRip.x264-ION10.mp4": No such file or directory
ls: cannot access "/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01.WEBRip.x264-ION10/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01E14.Time.to.Face.the.Music.WEBRip.x264-ION10.mp4": No such file or directory
```

But when I execute the line directly from the command line, it works. 
For example:

```
ll "/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01.WEBRip.x264-ION10/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01E14.Time.to.Face.the.Music.WEBRip.x264-ION10.mp4"
```

Gives as output:

```
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Pansysadmin users 275337817 Dec 15  2018 /volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01.WEBRip.x264-ION10/Find.Me.in.Paris.S01E14.Time.to.Face.the.Music.WEBRip.x264-ION10.mp4
```

Even when I execute the script with `sudo`, it gives the same error.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: The user said: *... in the file I could see the variables end on ^M, which probably means it is a dos file not a unix file. I was able to fix that via vi. And then all was well.*

Answer (score 9):

The quotes are not part of the filenames. You're trying to remove files such as `"file.txt"` but the file is actually called `file.txt`.

```
touch "file.txt"    # shell uses quotes; name is simply file.txt
ls "file.txt"       # quotes used by shell; success
ls file.txt         # no quotes; success
ls '"file.txt"'     # outer quotes used by shell to treat word-with-quotes as literal; failure
```

Fix the file of names so that the filenames are correct (i.e. without double quotes surrounding them), or modify your loop to remove the incorrect parts of the data.

I've just seen your comment about trying `sudo`. Please don't recourse to `sudo` without first understanding why you might need it. (You don't, here.) Otherwise one day you may end up breaking your system because you've inadvertently bypassed the protections it's tried to offer you.

Comment: `xargs` expects quoted input by default, so `xargs ls <Myfiles.txt` would probably work.

Answer (score 7):

To enlarge upon [roaima’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684729/80216),

- When you give commands to the shell,
  it does a lot of processing and interpretation on the command line. 
  For example:

  - If you type

    ```
    ls foo bar
    ```

    the shell runs `ls` with two arguments: `foo` and `bar`. 
    But if you type

    ```
    ls "foo bar"
    ```

    the shell runs `ls` with one argument: `foo bar`.
  - If you type

    ```
    rm north*
    ```

    the shell runs `rm` with many arguments,
    such as `north1`, `north42`, `northwest`, etc. 
    But if you type

    ```
    rm "north*"
    ```

    the shell runs `rm` with one argument: `north*`.
  - If you type

    ```
    echo Math tells us that 5 > 4.
    ```

    the shell creates a file called `4.`
    and writes `Math tells us that 5` to it. 
    Etc.
- When the `read` command reads input, it does none of that processing. 
  In particular, if you `read` a line of input
  that contains special characters like `*`, `>` and `"`,
  it just puts those characters into your `p` variable. 
  Spaces and tabs normally still have some special meaning,
  but you’re successfully suppressing that with `IFS=`. 
  Backslash (`\`) normally still has some special meaning,
  but you’re successfully suppressing that with `read -r`. 
  So `p` is getting set to the filenames with `"` at the beginning and end.
- Expanding the values of variables
  is one of the last things the shell does. 
  So, for example, you can do stuff like

  ```
  statement="Math tells us that 5 > 4."
  echo $statement
  ```

  and the shell will write `Math tells us that 5 > 4.` (to the terminal),
  because it doesn’t examine the contents of the `statement` variable
  for `>` characters.

  Note: the above is a bad example. 
  In general you should say

  ```
  echo "$statement"
  ```

  i.e., with quotes.
- So, when you say

  ```
  ls "$p"
  ```

  the shell runs `ls` with an argument that includes quote characters. 
  It’s essentially the same as saying

  ```
  ls '"/volume2/NBU/Downloads/AA_To be seen/Life.Itself … H264-FGT/RARBG.txt"'
  ```

  (note the quotes within quotes). 
  And the names of your actual files don’t include quote characters.