# Why does $HOME not expand the HOME variable here?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I wrote a simple script.

```
read -p "Enter the path: " path
echo "$path"
```

I give the input as

```
$HOME
```

And the output is:

```
$HOME
```

And if I write

```
echo "$HOME"
```

outputs

```
/home/sam
```

so why not in the former case?

Comment: Basically for the same reason why the C code `char *str = "foo()"; printf("%s\n", str);` doesn't call the function `foo()`. What is read with `read`, and what you print with `echo` is just data, not shell code. The shell isn't a macro processor that goes back to look at the expanded text to parse it again for further expansions. And it's very well that it isn't, since otherwise people could cause all kinds of havoc with e.g. filenames containing stuff that looks like shell syntax or expansions.

Comment: @ilkkachu then why does `echo "$HOME"` gives an output `/home/sam`.

Comment: Because now the command line, the command that actually gets parsed and interpreted for shell syntax does contain the expansion `$HOME`. Same as how `echo "$path"` expands `$path`. Similar to how `printf("%s\n", foo());` does call the function. It's the difference between code and data.

Comment: The shell evaluates variables in double quotes but not in single quotes. The `read` function is neither. It simply sets input into a variable. Just as a mental exercise, imagine how dangerous it would be if `read` always evaluated the variables.

Comment: OTOH, note that `read` without the `-r` option does do some mangling of the input data, namely takes backslashes as escapes for field splitting. (which you'd hardly ever want...) But it doesn't evaluate all shell syntax, or even only variable expansions (or quotes, or...)

Comment: For the "how" rather than the "why" see [How to expand variables inside read?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635778/how-to-expand-variables-inside-read)

Comment: Basically the same as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684729/80216 "‘‘ls’’ behaving differently inside and outside of bash script").

Comment: @klaus_03 although a lot has been covered by these comments, are you looking something like `eval printf '%s\n' "$path"`  ?  The use of `eval` is often associated with security risks, so have a look here before using it: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048?highlight=%28eval%29

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` becomes the **string** `$PATH`, not the "interpretation" of it. That interpretation only happens in specific contexts – for example, if you type it "bare" on an interactive shell command prompt; but definitely not in `read` (otherwise you couldn't use `read` to read text files containing `$`, for example!).

Remember, *expansion* is a functionality that you never want to have enabled everywhere – it would make it hard to write programs that pass around variables as variables, instead of their content. Thus, programming language designers (or in the case of shells, decades of more or less organic development) decide where that expansion happens, and where not. There's not really a "why" here: it's how it's defined.

You can `eval value="$path"` if you wish, then you get that. I do not recommend that, as it basically makes your entry a shell prompt and if the user enters, for example, `$(rm -rf /)`, that would allow them to delete everything...

All in all, I think this is more of a software design problem: what kind of things do you want to allow the user to do?

In this case, `$HOME` might pretty much be the only "special" case you'd want to allow. I'd recommend replacing that with `~`, as it's the canonical short form, and do something like:

```bsh
read "Enter foo bar baz:" raw_path
if [[ ( ! -d "${raw_path}" ) && "${raw_path:0:1}" = "~" ]]; then
  _path="${HOME}${raw_path:1:}"
else
  _path="${raw_path}"
fi
```

Comment: Alright got it, thanks!